# Geometry of roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Are they always equally-spaced on the unit circle, so that they always lie on the edges of equally-spaced wedges?

It seems like it, based on some sketching on paper, but if you can confirm or offer additional geometric information about these roots, please feel free.

Thanks,

Comment: That pretty well covers it, except to say that $z=1$ is always a root

Comment: They are the vertices of a regular $n$-gon.

Comment: Ok, got it thanks @WW1.

Comment: Thanks so much @AndréNicolas - yes, absolutely, now that I think about it.  But my aim right now is to use a wedge as my closed contour for integration and applying the residue theorem.  And I also have to compute some roots of unity and have one of these (they are poles in my problem statement) poles fall inside the wedge.  But I think I got it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$th roots of unity are given by $e^{2\pi i j / n}$ where $0 \leq j < n$. These lie on the unit circle at angles $2\pi i j /n$, which are equally spaced with angles $2\pi i / n$ between subsequent roots.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @mixedmath.